# Armature doesn't follow path

Tags: animation, armature, path

I have a problem with my armature, it should follow a path but it doesn't move from its initial position... the thin blue line between the armature and the curve appears and moves along the curve but the armature doesn't follow, I don't understand why!

I've linked the blend file here: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49394

thanks by advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

sorry, I've found out the eye of the Follow Path constraint was inactive, so it's solved !   ;)